# Make part of a cell italic using grid.table

Tags: css, r, gridextra

I am making a table and I would like to make parts of some cells italic. For example with the following code:

```
grid.table(iris[1:5, 1:3])
```

I get this table:

[image]

I would like to make the characters "Length" italic. I need the solution to be applicable to any cells in the table, not just the header.